# Proving this implication of zero conditional mean assumption

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, assumptions

I want to show that $E_{\epsilon} ( x_i \epsilon_i)=0$, where $\epsilon$ is the population error term.

I want to be very careful in every step with the language, so if there is even a small mistakes in what I say below, please point them out to me. Here we go.

First, the $0$ is a vector of dimension $[k, 1]$ assuming that $x_i$ is a vector of dimension $[k, 1]$. There are $k-1$ exogenous features and the first entry is $1$.

$E_{\epsilon} (x_i \epsilon_i)$

$= E_X( E_{\epsilon} (x_i \epsilon_i | X) )$ by the Law of Iterated Expectations

$= E_X( x_i E_{\epsilon} (\epsilon_i | X) )$ since $x_i$ is fixed due to the conditional part

$= E_X( x_i 0 )$ by the Conditional Mean assumption

$=0$

Is this a correct proof? Thanks!

Comment: This seems correct as far as the $E_\epsilon(\epsilon_i|X)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing, if you want, feel free to post it as an answer I will accept it. Up to you. Thanks